# Can the name of the macro be used as regular macro and as a string

Tags: c

In a Object-like macro, can the name of the macro be used as regular macro and as a string in the c code

```
#define MAX   0x1001
#define ANNE  0x1002
#define LENE  0x1003

void main()
{
 printf("%s is the name and number is %d ",MAX, MAX);
}
```

Comment: Why you did not just try to launch this program? I assure you that this program will not destruct your computer

Comment: `printf("%s is the name and number is %d ", "MAX", MAX);`....;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
#define MAX   0x1001
#define EXPLAIN_MACRO_INT(x) \
      printf("%s is the name and the number is %d\n", #x, x);
```

Be careful what argument you pass to this _INT macro. This is designed to print integers. Write macros for other types analogously.

Usage:

```
EXPLAIN_MACRO_INT(MAX)
```

Output:

MAX is the name and the number is 4097

---

### More generic

Or if you want to use it like

```
printf("%s is the name and the number is %d\n", EXPLAIN_MACRO(MAX));
```

then

```
#define EXPLAIN_MACRO(x) #x, x
```

This second version can be used with argument of all types - but now you must take care about formatting in printf.

Output is the same:

MAX is the name and the number is 4097

Comment: Nice, but why are you embedding the `printf` (and limiting to this format) in the macro? I suggest `#define EXPLAIN_MACRO(x) #x, x`

Comment: You can make it even more generic by indirectly stringifying the value and printing it as string. If the macro isn't defined, it will print itself.

Comment: @Alter Mann To save typing when explaining lot of symbols and to eliminate errors in printf format. Added your proposition as more generic alternative. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Use stringification:

```
 #define MAX   0x1001
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4

printf("%s is the name and number is %d ", str(MAX), MAX);

// note xstr(MAX) would expand to "1234"
```